# How to perform Android and iOS devices testing using Selenium 3.141 with C#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, appium, mobile-devices

As DesiredCapabilities are deprecated, do anyone know if there is any capability for Android and iOS devices to perform testing on actual devices using Selenium C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following as the capabilities to test Android or IOS apps

```
AppiumOptions opt = new AppiumOptions();
opt.AddAdditionalCapability("browserName", "chrome");
opt.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
opt.AddAdditionalCapability()...
```